# Rewrite Rule in .htaccess file for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain named

```
http://career.example.com
```

My URL Look Like

```
http://career.example.com/details.php?jid=17
```

Now I wan to show my URL look Like

```
http://career.example.com/details
```

I use this code in my .htaccess but not work

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^career\.example\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule    ^details/([0-9]+)/?$    details.php?jid=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is clearly a post to [Servers Fault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache friendly urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769548/apache-friendly-urls)

Comment: Your rule is redirecting `career.example.com` to `example.com` so you surely can't have `career.example.com/details/xxx` working