# Making user pages using PHP and MYSQL by getting user_name from URL: user/username

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP header redirect to redirect users from `account/?id=$id` to `user/$username`

Successfully it takes for instance `account/?id=1` to `user/samuel` as long as the user exists. Now, this page `user/samuel` is quite empty ( 404 ).

How do I make it return the user data in the `user/samuel` using something like `isset($_GET[])` manual? in addition of course to adding MYSQL query to retrieve data for the user which has username extracted from the URL, and get their data from database table. and I will be placing all the code in `user/index.php`

As long as I could make `account/?id=$id`  get the `$id` from URL ( parameter ) and do other db stuff I think it is also possible to get $username from the URL.. even though `user/?username` could do it but I don't want to include an `?` in the URL..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe `preg_match` ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty broad topic, what you need to do is parse the url - IE break it into parts and then match the url to a set of actions. This is commonly known as routing.

A naive implementation would be a:

```
$parts = explode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');

if ( $parts[-2] === 'user' && $parts[-1] ) {
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE username = ? OR id = ?");
   $result = $stmt->execute(array($parts[-1], array($parts[-1]));
   // ... do something if the user is found or not.
}
```

But this would fail if the url contains query parameters (`?foo=bar`) or a hash (`#foo`).

Instead you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to make sure you only use the path.

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = null;

// Match the url with a regular expression.
preg_match(/^\/user\/(\w*)$/, $path, $parts);

if ( count($parts) == 2 ) {
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE username = ? OR id = ?");
   $result = $stmt->execute(array($parts[-1], array($parts[-1]));
   // ... do something if the user is found or not.
}
```

But in the end you might want consider using a micro framework such as [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/), [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) or using the [Routing component from Symfony2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) so that you can concentrate on building your application rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Also not that I use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), extremely important if you are using user input in a database query.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better if you use Url Rewriting (aka friendly urls)

You can see this link which answers this same question, although your case is a little bit different.
[Apache friendly urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769548/apache-friendly-urls)

Since you can't convert $id to $username (both are different values) I would recommend to change the link to 'user/ID' instead of 'user/USERNAME'.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Actually I tried rewriting first, but it did not success as I was trying to redirect for instance user/index.php?id=1 to user/samuel ( I can not find a dynamic way to do that, because you know user IDs and usernames vary ) it does redirecting but only for users you provide IDs and usernames and I couldn't include PHP in htaccess.. so, I thought it would be better doing it with PHP and Mysql.
Thank you Eric :)

Comment: I understand. You could use in that case, when you are in 'user/USERNAME' read the entire URL and do an end/explode.

It would be something like this


 `$var = end(explode("/", $url));`

This way $var will contain the last "argument" although this can be dangerous since I can add anything to your URL and try to match it against your DB.

Why is it wrong to you to add a '?' to the URL?

Comment: oh thanks for the edit. maybe that's exactly what I need. working on it. thanks once again.